# Conditionally create stored procedure using TSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I'm writing a db update script which basically retrieve the current version number from the database then create a number of stored procedure if the version is valid. If the current version does not match the expected version then it should skip executing the code.

However I run into a problem when I write the script because CREATE PROCEDURE has to be the first statement in a batch, so it's not possible for me to insert if .. else statement before the create procedure statement.

I've also tried using GOTO but to no avail because GOTO doesn't span across multiple batches. Same thing applies to RETURN and RAISEERROR - the rest of the code will still execute.

Sample script:

```
IF @Version = '1.0' --doesn't work
BEGIN
    CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.uspCreateAccount
    AS BEGIN
    --The rest of the code goes here
    END
END
```

Can anyone provide some insight on this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can accomplish this using the `exec` functionality.

```
IF @Version = '1.0'
BEGIN
    --Drop it if it already exists
    IF OBJECT_ID('uspCreateAccount', 'P') IS NOT NULL
        EXEC ('DROP PROCEDURE uspCreateAccount')
    --Recreate it.
    EXEC('
          CREATE PROCEDURE uspCreateAccount
          AS BEGIN
          --The rest of the code goes here
          END
    ')
END
```

Comment: Seems good. Will try it out. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You can use `exec` to run a SQL command in a new scope.  The following snippet will run even when `dbo.YourProc` already exists, because the SQL command inside `exec()` will never be parsed in that case.

```
if not exists (select * from sys.procedures where name = 'YourProc')
    exec ('create procedure dbo.YourProc as select 1 as a')
go
alter procedure dbo.YourProc
as
select ...
```

This construct creates an empty stub procedure if the procedure does not exist.  If the procedure exists, it runs `alter`.  So it preserves rights that have been granted on the procedure.

Comment: Sorry but this is not exactly what I want. What I'm asking for is if the version is not correct then don't create the procedure.

Comment: Check out @cbeckner's answer.  Placing the actual body inside `exec` is harder to read and maintain, so I try to avoid that situation, for example by checking the version in a different database call.

Comment: Yes his solution seems to work. Just wondering is there any better solution out there? Because maintainability becomes a concern if I use that approach.

Comment: +1 for preserving permissions

Comment: @user1928346: You could change the program that runs the script (or if it's a human, the instructions for the human.)  Use a different script to check the version, and if the version does not match, run the other script.

Comment: Using something similar to my answer below, we maintain a (growing) script that will check the patch level on the database and if a procedure is created in v1.0, then in subsequent edits later in the script, we can choose the appropriate alter/drop & recreate/drop action safe in the knowledge that the v1.0 patch has been applied.  Maintaining version information in the database also keeps a v1.1 patch from being applied, if v1.0 never was. i.e. `@Version >= 1.0`